# Setting a property of a View Controller embedded in Navigation Controller via Tab Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My app contains a Tab Bar Controller at the root which has to three tabs - each of which are View Controllers embedded in their own Navigation Controllers. Like this: Tab Controller -> Nav Controller -> View Controller. 
I'm trying to set a property of the second tab's view controller from the first tab like this (as I would when preparing for segue)

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController     

if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1) {
        ((CreateViewController *)viewController).myProperty = YES;
}
```

The method is being called as expected, but as soon as I attempt to set the property the app crashes and I receive the error:

```
-[UINavigationController setAppearedFromTabBar:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc913d5f510
```

I have a feeling this has to do with the fact that the View Controller (CreateViewController *) is embedded in a Nav Controller. Do I need to pass the info to the Nav Controller which in turn will pass it to the View Controller? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Clearly you have reference to navigationController instead of CreateViwController. I would try sth like: `(CreateViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)viewController topViewController].myProperty = YES;`

Comment: very good, it works, thanks! I just had to add extra parentheses so - `((CreateViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)viewController topViewController]).myProperty = YES;`

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer, so you may accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly you have reference to navigationController instead of CreateViwController.

```
((CreateViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)viewController topViewController]).myProperty = YES;
```